# How to use window as a Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, client, raspberry-pi3, communication, serversocket

ı'm working on a project which is about two raspberry pies' communication.I created a server and a client,ı want one raspberry pi to be server to send a input and another raspberry pi to be client to take the output but ı don't have second raspberry pi,How can ı use windows/my laptop as second raspberry pi. Could you please help me about that?

Comment: see this link : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13425/server-and-client-between-pc-and-raspberry-pi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use windows as raspberry pi and connect the windows with another raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083217/how-to-use-windows-as-raspberry-pi-and-connect-the-windows-with-another-raspberr)

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?
How are you two terminals supposed to communicate?
You need to make your question more clear.
If your server and your client are supposed to communicate over HTTP, you don't need to have two raspis; as long as your app can get your app to run on a machine, you can use it as a server/client

Comment: I'm using Python 3,ı want to send input from first raspi and change the output  from second raspi.For example ı have a button,when ı press the button,ı want one message to be seen on the screen,when ı release the button ı want the message on the screen to be changed.I did everything correctly up to here.Now I want to use first raspi as button and ı want the messages to be seen and changed on second raspi.But the problem is that ı don't have second raspi,my boss said that ı could use my windows/laptop as second raspi.I could not find  how to do that