# How to use windows as raspberry pi and connect the windows with another raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, communication

I'm using Python 3,ı want to send input from first raspi and change the output from second raspi.For example ı have a button,when ı press the button,ı want one message to be seen on the screen,when ı release the button ı want the message on the screen to be changed.I did everything correctly up to here.Now I want to use first raspi as button and ı want the messages to be seen and changed on second raspi.But the problem is that ı don't have second raspi,my boss said that ı could use my windows/laptop as second raspi.I could not find how to do that –

Answer (score 1):

You can't "use windows as a raspberry pi".

What your boss probably meant was to run the same code on your own computer and have the Pi communicate with it...

You would need to look into using the `socket` module or a library like SocketIO or ZMQ, where your Windows machine would "listen" for incoming requests on some port, and the raspberry pi would have to connect explicitly to that port on the remote machine

If by "screen" you mean a web browser, then you would just use Javascript to update the display, and the backing API server (of any language) would store your change

Comment: Thank you for your response,ı have used socket module ı have codes for client  and server side,am ı suppose to run the client's code on raspberry on the screen connected by HDMI and run the server's code on windows?

Comment: I'm not sure what HDMI has to do with anything, but yes that sounds reasonable

Comment: Can ı run input from raspberry pi as server and get the output as client from my laptop by wireless connection?

Comment: Either system can be the client or server or both

Comment: Could you tell me how to connect raspberry server from laptop without using SSH,Remote Desktop Connection or VNC? Can ı connect by using script? or ı should write code and run it in python?

Comment: I mentioned two libraries in my answer that are not VNC or SSH